# how to secure connection string in visual studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string, ip-address

I want to know if there's a way to make my connection-string work only with one specific server!

I want it to stop working when the database is moved to another server even with the same IP address as the old one!

Is it possible to use physical address instead of IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use server name in place of IP address. Do as below in connection string.

```
Data Source=ServerName
```

Comment: the name is weak as the IP, we can change the name of server as we can change the IP I want to use something that users can't change lik Physical adress